# Matlab, assigning a single character to cells of a cell array

Tags: matlab

It eludes me how to assign a single character to an array of cells (that are themselves nested within a cell array), without using a for-loop.
How can the following be achieved with a single line, not using a for-loop?

```
tc = cell(1,3);
tc{2} = cell(1,10);
for ii=1:length(tc{2})
    tc{2}{ii} = 'N';
end
```

For clarity, this is what the contents of the variables look like (and should look like) in the variable editor:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how:

```
tc{2}(1:10)={'N'};
```

For more insight, see these:

- [Access Data in Cell Array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)
- [Multilevel Indexing to Access Parts of Cells](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/multilevel-indexing-to-access-parts-of-cells.html)

Comment: Thank you!! Actually makes sense. I just didn't get it.